# MSSQL use trim on select

Tags: sql-server-2008

So i am trying to do ltrim or rtrim in a sql statement without having to explicitly type all the column names. So basically instead of doing

```
    select ltrim(col1), ltrim(col2)... from table 1
```

i want to do something like

```
    select ltrim(*) from table1.
```

I understand that typically it is bad practice to use select * but in this case it makes sense. This is for Sql-server 2008. There are some similar questinos but could not find question for this particular issue. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I don't thnk it's possible.

Comment: Thanks that is the conclusion that i am coming to as well.

Comment: You can easily add trims on all columns with dynamic sql, but it has it's own drawbacks...

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically create the query or make a stored procedure in which you pass the table name..

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@tablename as varchar(255)='table1',
@columns as varchar (max),
@SQL VARCHAR(max)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ',LTRIM('+quotename(C.name)+')'
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id(@tablename) and
               C.is_computed=0
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

         SET @columns=@colsUnpivot

SET @SQL = '(SELECT '+@columns+'  FROM  [dbo].['+@tablename+'] )';
EXEC(@SQL)
```